# Open child window

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I need to open a child window like the alert box,
I already created a popup for that, it is working, but I need the popup open like alert and want to enter data and update, required for editing data from a table, I need to open alert box while clicking the edit button, I already created a popup window to do that, I tried adding that code here...

code of main table is:

```js
function poupdata(url){
 window.open(url,"edit","width=500,height=550px");
 }
```

```html
<html>
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>Sl No</th><th>head 1</th><th>head 2</th><th>head 3</th><th>Edit</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>data 1</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="poupdata('edit.php?slno=1')"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>data 1</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="poupdata('edit.php?slno=2')"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>data 1</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="poupdata('edit.php?slno=3')"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>data 1</td><td>data 2</td><td>data 3</td><td><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="poupdata('edit.php?slno=4')"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
</html>
```

and the     edit.php page like

```html
   
    <html>
    <form method="POST"><table>
    <tr><td>Data 1</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 2</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 3</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Data 34</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
```

in this while clicking the submit button data read from the input fields and get updated in database,
and after updation sucessfull i need to close this and reload the main page automaticaly,
how can i do this

Comment: so what is your question ? do you want a popup/dialog which gets data from user and pass the data to the server when the user click on submit?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and look at these examples, i am sure this is what you are looking for:

[Bootstrap Modals](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

[Modals Popup](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)